# Generate Change Scripts from a TFS and Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, tfs, project

Is there a way to generate change scripts from a Visual Studio and TFS project? I would like to either choose two versions of the database or enter a date range and get change scripts that I can pass off to a DBA to apply to the production database.

I do not have access to the production schema in order to do a schema compare.
My DBA wants SQL scripts and will not use snapshot method.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2008 and later.

Help!

Comment: Dacpacs? could be an option

Comment: Dacpacs are snapshots and they don't want to use that method. The DBAs, while not actively involved in the development process want to be able to review the changes (see them individually) before touching the server.

Comment: The dacpac can be used to generate the sql script, but not execute it. That way the DBA can review all he wants. Use the `sqlpackage /action:script` option and specify the source to be your dacpac and the target to be the production server connection string. That will not change the server in any way and allow them to inspect the changes.

Comment: This might work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your dba's attitude is blocking your ability to deliver high quality software on a regular cadence. Comparing with production is the correct and supported method to achive a change script. And remember the tools you are using are built and supported by the SQL Server team.

If you know when the current production version was shipped you can create a workspace and get that specific version of your code. If you compile it you should have a .dacpac for that version and you can use that in the compare.

Another option would be to ask the DBA to restore the last production version to another server so that you can 'test' the script. You can then generate your script from there.

Whatever you choose you need to raise this with management as a blocker for continuous delivery.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and you are preaching to the choir. Based on the replies I have gotten, I suspect that the answer to my question is simply No. Thanks! :-)

Comment: No, it was to compare with the previous DackPack that you shipped or to a clone of production. 